# Writing files to a path with name incrementation

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

In a `Unity3D` script, I have the following that simply writes a file (an image) to a path:

```
var path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ocr.jpg";
FileOperations.Create(blah, path);
```

Of course in a `static` Utility program elsewhere, I have implemented this helper function as follows:

```
public static void Create(byte[] bytes, string path)
{
    var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

    using ( var binary = new BinaryWriter(file) )
    {
        binary.Write(bytes);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

I realised my implementation would only create one file; i.e. over-write an existing file with the same name (`ocr.jpg`) so I wrote the following code:

```
public static void Create(byte[] bytes, string path)
{
    if ( !File.Exists(path) )
    {
        var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

        using ( var binary = new BinaryWriter(file) )
        {
            binary.Write(bytes);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {                                                       
        int counter = 1;
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ocr" + "_" + counter + ".jpg";

        var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

        using ( var binary = new BinaryWriter(file) )
        {
            binary.Write(bytes);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I realised every time I run the app, the `counter` is set back to `1`, so now my `ocr_1.jpg` is over-written!

(Never mind that this half-solution is already ugly, because it brings in some Unity-specific stuff. I was hoping not to include the `using UnityEngine` in my helper utility class.)

Next, I tried to do it recursively, as follows:

```
public static void Create(byte[] bytes, string path)
{
    if ( !File.Exists(path) )
    {
        var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

        using ( var binary = new BinaryWriter(file) )
        {
            binary.Write(bytes);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {                                                       
        int counter = 1;
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ocr" + "_" + counter + ".jpg";

        Create(bytes, path);
    }
}
```

But I got a `StackOverFlow` error message. I don't understand why though, because the checking should go on until there is no file with the same name, etc...

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and how I can achieve my goal of running the app as many times as I want and getting images created sequentially: `ocr.jpg`, `ocr_1.jpg`, `ocr_2.jpg`, `ocr_3.jpg`, etc...

Also, it would be great if I find out how to do this in a way that my utility class does not have to include unity-related stuff; i.e. only have `using System.IO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was hoping not to include the `using UnityEngine` in my helper utility
>   class

You don't have to. You can use its fully qualified name that includes its namespace:

```
UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath
```

Few things to know:

**1**.Always catch Exceptions when reading or writing to a file.

**2**.Don't do something like this: `Application.persistentDataPath + "/ocr" + "_" + counter + ".jpg";`.

Not a good idea to concatenate file name with "`+`" since that is **not** portable across platforms. Use `Path.Combine` for that.

---

Here is how I would implement this:

Use `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` to save the counter. Each time you want to save the image, use `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` to read the counter then save the image with `File.WriteAllBytes`. If saving is successful, increment the counter then save it with `PlayerPrefs.SetInt`.

Roughly something like below:

```
public static void Create(byte[] dataToSave)
{
    //Load old counter
    int counter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_counter_", 0);

    //Concatenate file name
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath, "ocr");
    tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "_");
    tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, counter.ToString() + ".jpg");

    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempPath)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempPath));
    }
    //Debug.Log(path);

    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, dataToSave);
        Debug.Log("Saved Data to: " + tempPath.Replace("/", "\\"));

        //Increment Counter
        counter++;

        //Save current Counter
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_counter_", counter);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed To PlayerInfo Data to: " + tempPath.Replace("/", "\\"));
        Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you pass in a path that already exists and

```
path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ocr" + "_" + counter + ".jpg";
```

also exists, you keep on calling Create method without incrementing counter, hence stack overflow. Consider passing counter value to the recursive create method, and updating it in every iteration, until it hits a filename that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting a StackOverflow is due to the filling of the methods [Call Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). In your code, the `counter` variable is a local variable to the method and is never incremented. Therefore, every time there is a recursive call to the `Create` method, an identical call (argument-wise) is made.

As a high-level solution, you should do two things:

- Track the value of the `counter` throughout the recursive calls
- Make sure to increment the value of the counter with every recursive call of `Create`

You could track the state of the `counter` variable either by having it as a global variable (which sometimes is not a good idea) or to keep it part of the `Create` method arguments.